# BlockingCollection Take() Blocking Forever

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

I have a simple producer consumer setup using a blocking collection. The consumer sits in a loop for the duration of our application waiting for the consumer to put items in the collection, then takes the item out and writes it to a serial port. For some reason collection.Take() blocks forever when there are items in the collection. For this app we might have one or many of these ProducerConsumers active at a time. They behave the same regardless.

```
public class ProducerConsumer 
{
    private Task _backgroundWorker;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private BlockingCollection<Data> _dataQueue;

    public ProducerConsumer() 
    {
        _dataQueue = new BlockingCollection<Data>();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _backgroundWorker = new Task(() => DoWork(_cancellationTokenSource.Token), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        _backgroundWorker.Start();
    }

    public void AddData(Data data) 
    {
        _dataQueue.Add(data);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_dataQueue.Count);
    }

    private void DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _dataQueue.Take(cancellationToken); //This is blocking forever

                //DoWork
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException) { }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

When running this the print statement is incrementing so we definitely have data in the Collection, but for whatever reason Take() continues to block.

It isn't throwing an Exception either.

Cancellation is requested with Dispose(), but I didn't add that here. It isn't called being called early.

I have tried using .GetConsumingEnumerable() and that also blocks forever.

Am I starting the Task wrong? Could I be running out of threads?

I've considered using a BackgroundWorker instead of a Task, but according to [MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_Threads) Task is preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tasks are created and run with `Task.Run`. If you want a long-running task, use TaskFactory.StartNew. There's *no reason* to use cold tasks like you do. There are many other weird things, eg `DoWork` returns a `Task` even though it's a synchronous method. Finally, you don't show anything calling `AddData()`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. AddData is being called in many places and it seemed redundant to add a line showing it being called. What do you mean by cold tasks? 

Do work was originally void, I changed it to see if that makes a difference. I'll update the question to change it back to void

Comment: Cold task is a task created with `new` that needs `Start()` to run. This is never used

Comment: Did you check the documetnation examples, eg [How to: Add and Take Items Individually from a BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-take-items)? The code there is a lot simpler than what you posted. I wouldn't use BlockingCollection in any case because it requires blocking

Comment: `Take` and `GetConsumingEnumerable` will wait until either a new item is added or you notify the collection that you are finished adding anything by calling `CompleteAdding`.

Comment: @ckuri New items are being added, but take isn't continuing for some reason.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I changed the task.Start to Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); but I still get the same behavior. Trying the ActionBlock now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't try to create my own producer/consumer implementation, especially not one that blocks. The simple producer/consumer scenario can be handled easily with an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data). The ActionBlock has an internal queue to which multiple concurrent producers can post messages. The ActionbBlock will process the queued messages in the background using the worker method passed to its constructor :

```
class SerialWorker
{
    ActionBlock<Data>  _serialBlock;

    public SerialWorker()
    {    
        _serialBlock=new ActionBlock<Data>(data=>DoWork(data));
    }

    //The worker action can be synchronous 
    private void DoWork(Data data)
    {
    }
    //or asynchronous
    private async Task DoWorkAsync(Data data)
    {
    }


    //Producer Code
    //While the application runs :
    public void PostData(Data data)
    {
        _serialBlock.Post(someData);
    }

//When the application finishes 
//Tell the block to shut down and wait for it to process any leftover requests
    public async Task Shutdown()
    {
        _serialBlock.Complete();    
        await _serialBlock.Completion;
    }
```

The worker method can be async, eg `new ActionBlock<Data>(data=>DoWorkAsync(data))` will work just fine. This allows the use of asynchronous methods without blocking inside the worker itself.

New messages are posted with `ActionBlock.Post`. When it's time to shut down, the application should call `Complete()` to notify the actionblock and await for it to complete. The ActionBlock will stop receiving more messages and process anything still left in its buffer before terminating.

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't know that existed. That looks far better than what we're currently doing. I'll take a look and let you know. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @mAniC check the rest of the docs too. You can create pipelines of connected blocks, put limits to how many things can be buffered at a time etc